# Python: How to get the same sorting order as Windows file name sorting?

Tags: python, natsort

I want to sort filename in python like Windows.
I prepare four files(or folders).

```
1. [abc]abc【abc】
2. [abc]abcabc【abc】
3. 001
4. 002
```

These are sorted in Windows(ascending order) : 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

But in python,
When Using sorted function or natsort(ns.PATH) : 3 -> 4 -> 2-> 1

How to solve this problem?

Comment: The Windows order is not because of the names, but it's putting the directories first, then plain files. You could declare a custom Python sort key with (file type, filename).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it in the order that file explorer would put the filenames in by default, then you'll want the folders first and then the files, and both sections in alphabetical order.

The code below stores all the files in the directory in exactly the same order as file explorer in the list `this_dir`.

```
import os

folder_path = "C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\Folder"

files = []
folders = []

for f in os.listdir(folder_path):
    fname = os.path.join(folder_path, f)
    if os.path.isdir(fname):
        folders.append(f)
    if os.path.isfile(fname):
        files.append(f)

this_dir = folders + files


print("\n".join([" - " + f for f in this_dir]))
```

Output:

```
 - abc
 - abcabc
 - 001.txt
 - 002.txt
 - abc.txt
 - abcabc.txt
```

This is the same order in which file explorer lists them. (`abc` and `abcabc` are both folders)

Comment: Sorry, But this is not well working.

If i have three files [1.txt, 2.txt, 10.txt],

then os.listdir give me : [1.txt, 10.txt, 2.txt]

Also i means special characters(【 or [  or etc.), not only 'abc'.

Comment: What order were you expecting these files to be in? File explorer should display them as `1.txt`, `10.txt`, `2.txt` because it evaluates the names character by character. The first characters are `1`, `2`, and `1`. `2` comes after `1`, so `2.txt` is last. The second characters of the two filenames starting with `1` are `.`, and `0`. `.` comes before `0`, so `1.txt` is first, making the order `1.txt`, `10.txt`, then `2.txt`.

Comment: If you want to sort them in a different order, you would have to implement your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: This answer is not useful. File explorer does what is called a natural sort so 2 will be listed before 10, 30 before 100, etc. One could simple use glob and get the same results as this multiline function does.